# jQuery - Scale and rotate transition simultaneously on clicked div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div rotate and grow on click using jQuery. Here is my js:

```
var degrees = Math.random() * 20;

var flag = 0;

$(".rotate").click(function() {
    if (flag == 0) {
        flag = 1;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',

            '-webkit-transform': 'scale(2)',
            '-moz-transform': 'scale(2)',
            '-ms-transform': 'scale(2)',
            '-o-transform': 'scale(2)',
            'transform': 'scale(2)'
        });
        degrees = Math.random() * 20;
    } else {
        flag = 0;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'
        });
    };
});
```

My issue is that the rotation was working, until I added the scaling, at which point the div would grow, but not rotate. Why is this, and how can I fix it? Just to add, in my css, I have included the transition so that the transforms are animated. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/4Lhyaxwn/

Answer (score 1):

IF you give the same property tow times it gets overwritten. try this

```
var degrees = Math.random() * 20;

var flag = 0;

$(".rotate").click(function() {
    if (flag == 0) {
        flag = 1;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',


        });
        degrees = Math.random() * 20;
    } else {
        flag = 0;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `transform` property by setting it twice. Set the value of transform to `rotate(xdeg) scale(y)`

So, it will look like

```
'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
```

Also, update browser specific properties, accordingly. [(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/m7c6es65/1/)